# C# interface how to hide code

Tags: c#, interface

I developed a class library containing an interface and an inherited class:

```
public interface testInterface
{
    string GetAge(int year);
}
```

and a class that extends this interface

```
public class testClass : testInterface
{
    public string GetAge(int year)
    {
        int age = DateTime.Today.Year - year;
        return string.Format("Your age is {0}", age);
    }
}
```

in another solution I created a console application and I referenced the class library dll. in the driver i created an object:

```
testClassLibrary1.testInterface obj = new testClassLibrary1.testClass();
```

and I called the method GetAge();
When I debug, I can still see the code of the method getAge()
How can I hide this code? I mean isn't the interface used to hide the method abstract? please advise.

Comment: You can never truly hide code so you might as well not bother with it. Even if you put it in a separate assembly and have an interface-reference to it, the user can just disassemble the dll. 

As for using a polymorphed variable: this only changes how the compiler treats a variable, not how you as a user can physically inspect it.

Comment: I mean I want this shown in the title: [from metadata], and when the debugger reaches the method in metadata, I am not able to view the code of the method

Answer (score 3):

You could simply not deliver the debug information (*.pdb) to the party that's using the dll.

However, the interface is meant to hide the implementation from the compiler. You can change it and the program will still compile because it's not dependent on it. The instant you have a single implementation active, it's very useful to debug into it.

Interfaces are a way to abstract things, not to hide or secure things.

Comment: I mean I want this shown in the title: [from metadata], and when the debugger reaches the method in metadata, I am not able to view the code of the method

Comment: @Samer_Azar You can make it more difficult for your user by not delivering the *.pdb files. But he will still be able to perfectly decompile your code. If you need real security, the only way is to not deliver *any* code to your user and instead have some kind of service that your user can call that runs in an environment you control.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in an approach which is not [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) with interfaces.

Comment: I mean I want this shown in the title: [from metadata], and when the debugger reaches the method in metadata, I am not able to view the code of the method

Answer (score 1):

As @nvoigt said, the only thing you could do is to not include any symbols (*.pdb files) with your dll/package.

However bear in mind that you are writing managed code and anyone using a managed code decompiler tool like Reflector or DotPeek can easily inspect the code.

A possible solution is to obfuscate your code in order to make it harder to see what you are doing but you can never truly prevent people from decompiling it. Where there's a will...

Comment: I mean I want this shown in the title: [from metadata], and when the debugger reaches the method in metadata, I am not able to view the code of the method

Answer (score 1):

You can never hide your code from debug mode. The only way to do this is it have that code execute outside of the scope of the Visual Studio application you're running.

FYI: In terms of hiding code visibility at a programming interface level, there are various options available, for example the 'new' keyword to hide derived members, and on a more basic level various protection levels for your classes, properties and methods, e.g. internal, protected, etc.

Comment: I mean I want this shown in the title: [from metadata], and when the debugger reaches the method in metadata, I am not able to view the code of the method